# Prevent PowerShell script from being read

Tags: powershell

I have the below PowerShell script (**myscript.ps1**) in which I ask for username and password. Depending on the username and password it copies a file to a certain destination.

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
if ($credentials.Username -eq "user1" -And $credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password -eq "pass1") 
{ Copy-Item "test1.pdf" "\test\test1.pdf"; } 
else 
{ Copy-Item "test2.pdf" "\test\test2.pdf"; }
```

**Requirement**: I want to make this file protected so no one can edit it and see the username and password.

### PS2EXE

I found a solution found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1) which converts the PowerShell script to an `.exe` file. When I originally run the script using PowerShell a dialog box appears allowing me to enter the username and password:

[image: Get-Credential dialog box]

After the .exe is generated and when I run it the credentials dialog box no longer appears. Instead, the console appears saying "Credential:"

[image: PS2EXE console]

I don't know why? I want the credentials form to still appear when running the exe. Any thoughts please?

Comment: You can't protect the script.  But you can keep the uname and password in an encrypted file and read them in at runtime.

Comment: @RyanBemrose could you send me a reference how this can be done please?

Comment: That doesn't sound secure, the script would then need the encryption key hardcoded, which is just as bad as having the password.     Why not just apply an ACL to the script file?

Comment: [This article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx) shows how to store encrypted passwords in the Windows Credential manager or in a Secure String.  You can websearch for "powershell secure password" for other tutorials on storing passwords in an encrypted file.

Comment: @Burt_Harris Is there an ACL you can apply that allows executing the file but not reading it?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestions. I actually find a solution where the script can be converted to an exe as shown here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1 but after I convert my script and run the resulted .exe file instead of the credentials appearing, the console appear saying "credintial:" not sure why the credentials form no longer appears? I've updated my question

Comment: Is this a question about how to prevent users reading the contents of a script (hence obfuscating as an EXE) or how to authenticate a user prior to performing an action?

Comment: @CharlieJoynt prevent users reading the contents of a script.

Comment: In the example given, it seems that the person executing the script/EXE would have permission to copy the file either way, if they chose to do so manually. Other than validating the users, the credentials don't play a part in the actual copying of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q: Why does the EXE prompt with "Credential"?**

This isn't an answer to the real question, and is based on guessing/supposition about PS2EXE, but I hope it is useful to clear up some confusion.

Having looked briefly at the PS2EXE page linked above, it seems that this utility encodes the script in Base64 and bundles it with a lightweight (?) custom PowerShell host. When run, I suppose the EXE starts the host, decodes the script and runs it.

The problem is that the `Get-Credential` cmdlet is running within a PS host that probably can't interact with the desktop. That is, it can't put up the GUI prompt for credentials. It therefore needs to prompt for the **Credential** property on the command line, explaining why you see that behaviour.

**Workaround with Read-Host?**

Instead of trying to use `Get-Credential` to prompt for username and password, you could embrace what PS2EXE seems to be doing and just use `Read-Host`:

```
$UserName = Read-Host "Enter username"
$Password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString

$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserName,$Password

if ($credentials.Username -eq "user1" -And $credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password -eq "pass1") 
{ ... }
```

Using `-AsSecureString` will hide the password on the screen. The **$Password** variable will be of type `System.Security.SecureString`, which can be used to create a **PSCredential** object as shown.

You'd need to test this, but it seems that you're able to read from the shell but not from a GUI prompt.

And just to be clear: none of this is anywhere near best-practice security. If you need authentication/authorization for these activities, step back and look at the problem again.

**Workaround with two scripts?**

It seems that PS2EXE doesn't support `-AsSecureString` in the same way that normal PowerShell does, i.e. it doesn't hide the characters. A possible workaround for this would be to collect the username and password from the user in one script and then pass them to a PS2EXE-converted script for processing.

*Launch-MyScript.ps1:*

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential
& MyScript.exe $Credentials.Username $Credentials.Password
```

*MyScript.exe* (coverted with PS2EXE):

```
param($Username,$Password)

$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username,$Password

if ($Credentials.Username -eq "user1" -and
  $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password -eq "pass1")
{
  ...
}
```

The user runs *Launch-MyScript.ps1* and completes the password prompt. Then the EXE is run automatically with the username and password passed in as arguments. Note that, as shown above, the password is a Secure String. Test this; I'm not using PS2EXE so it's a theoretical solution at the moment.

If you can't pass **$Password** along the pipeline as a Secure String object, you can convert it to text with `ConvertFrom-SecureString` in the first script, then conver it back with `ConvertTo-SecureString` in the second one.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. So what shall I do then when the Credential property appears on the command line?

Comment: If command-line prompts are acceptable, then you could prompt for username and password individually using `Read-Host` and drop any pretence at using a PSCredential object at all.

Comment: could you show me how please? as I'm not familiar with this. Also there is no way to convert it to .exe and has the Get-Credential form appearing?

Comment: Have updated by answer. It does seem to me that we're heading off down the wrong track to solve what you are ultimately trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've done this but now I'm trying to mask the password but it doesn't work using `$Password = Read-Host -assecurestring "Enter password"` any thoughts?

Comment: `Read-host -AsSecureString` throws up a GUI prompt for me, so probably won't work in the same way that `Get-Credential` doesn't work. If confidentiality of the password is important, then we should stop going down this path and consider what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, here is what I want. I want my_script to check username and password, because depending on them certain following actions will occur. The other thing is that I don't want users to be able to see what's inside it except me, and this has nothing to do at all by the windows credentials.

Comment: Updated the solution to show how you would use `Read-Host -AsSecureString` to build a credential object, which you can then use in the way you do in the script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126557/discussion-between-tak-and-charlie-joynt).

Answer (score 0):

According to this article http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/protect-your-powershell-scripts you should first set ur execution policy to AllSigned by  Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned, then create a certificate using makecert cmdlet.

Then u can sign single script using Set-AuthenticodeSignature cmdlet or use .pfx File to Sign a Script which appears even safer.

Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: I think the ask is about hiding the script contents. Signing a script controls the *execution* of the script, not whether someone can read the file contents.